# How to show bottom sheet dialog in Jetpack compose on EachRow item click?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I am facing an issue while showing the bottom sheet dialog in jetpack compose on each row item click. When I click on an item the app crashes.

Here is my `LazyColumn` code:

```
//Setup Recyclerview
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun SetRecyclerview(viewModel: UserViewModel, paddingValues: PaddingValues) {
    val isLoading = viewModel.isLoading.value
    var showSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var sheetUser: User? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    //Creating a variable for the StateFlow variable
    val userList = viewModel.userData.collectAsState().value

    if (showSheet) {
        ShowBottomSheetDialog(user = sheetUser!!)
        sheetScope.launch {
            sheetState.show()
        }
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        ProgressBarComponent()
    } else {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 5.dp, 0.dp, 5.dp)
        ) {
            userList.forEach { user ->
                items(user.results.size) {
                    EachRow(user = user.results[it], onClick = {
                        showSheet = true
                        sheetUser = user.results[it]
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `ShowBottomSheetDialog` function:

```
 //ShowBottomSheetDialog
@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ShowBottomSheetDialog(user: User) {
    sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    sheetScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = { BottomSheetItem(user = user) },
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.White,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
    ) {}
}
```

Here is `BottomSheetItem` function:

```
//Bottom Sheet Item
@Composable
fun BottomSheetItem(user: User) {
    Log.e("TAG", "BottomSheetItem: " + user.email)   
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a non-zero height composable in BottomSheetItem?

Comment: It crashes when I click on each row item to show bottom sheet. I am unable to get the issue.

Comment: ...and the logs? you should provide errors